# Writing a bash script more elegantly

Tags: bash, shell

So I have the following script working as a daily workaround until the dev people fix:

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i 's/,/;/g' /file_path/filename_date.csv
sed -i 's/NAME;NAME/NAME,NAME/g' /file_path/filename_date.csv
```

It works but when I look at it I think something is missing or isn't elegant.
Maybe is my way of thinking being so much straight forward.

What is your opinion?

Comment: What is the script supposed to do? Replace all `,` (except those between `NAME` and `NAME`) with a semicolon?

Comment: Yes. when doing the first one it replaces all ```,``` with ```;``` but at one field ```NAME,NAME``` doing that command changes the ```,``` with ```;``` and I need that field to be with ```,``` if not, importing the csv file gets messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
sed -i 's/,/;/g; s/NAME;NAME/NAME,NAME/g' file
```

or

```
sed -i -e 's/,/;/g' -e 's/NAME;NAME/NAME,NAME/g' file
```

Comment: Thank you for replies. 
I was complicating too much on my head but it is still straight forward your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with extended regular expressions and capture groups:

```sh
sed -Ei 'y/,/;/;s/(NAME);\1/\1,\1/g'
```

The [`y`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-y-_0028transliterate_0029-command) command is for transliteration.